# Image analysis - fiber recognition

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing, f#, wolfram-mathematica

I am new to image analysis. Do you know how to binarize this image in such a way to get the fibers only?

[image: Fibers in the liquid]

I have tried different threshold techniques etc, but I was not successful. I do not mind what tool I should use but I prefer `.NET` or `Matlab`.

PS: I did not know where to put my answer, so I put it at StackOverflow.

Comment: As an alternative to SO, try http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have asked there as well and the question can be found [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/201/image-analysis-fiber-recognition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems you are having difficulty translating the proposed Mathematica solutions into MATLAB. Here is my attempt:

#### @Nakilon solution

```
%# read image
I = im2double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KCd1.jpg'));

%# ImageAdjust[]
II = I;
for k=1:size(II,3)
    mn = min(min( II(:,:,k) )); mx = max(max( II(:,:,k) ));
    II(:,:,k) = ( II(:,:,k) - mn ) ./ (mx-mn);
end

%# Sharpen[]
II = imfilter(II, fspecial('unsharp'));

%# MinDetect[], MaxDetect[]
II = rgb2gray(II);
mn = imextendedmin(II,0.3,8);
mx = imextendedmax(II,0.7,8);

%# pad image because Mathematica handles border cases differently than MATLAB
pad = 30;
q = padarray(mn, [pad pad], 'symmetric', 'both');

q = medfilt2(q, [5 5]*2+1, 'symmetric');                 %# MedianFilter[]
q = ordfilt2(q, 1, ones(2*5+1), 'symmetric');            %# MinFilter[]
q = ordfilt2(q, (25*2+1)^2, ones(25*2+1), 'symmetric');  %# MaxFilter[]
q = ordfilt2(q, 1, ones(20*2+1), 'symmetric');           %# MinFilter[]

%# un-pad image
q = q(pad+1:end-pad, pad+1:end-pad, :);

%# ImageSubtract[], ImageMultiply[], ImageAdd[]
a = imsubtract(mn,q)==1;    %# a = mn; a(q) = false;
b = immultiply(mx,q);       %# b = mx & q;
c = imadd(a,b);             %# c = a | b;

%# show images
figure(1)
subplot(121), imshow(mn)
subplot(122), imshow(mx)
figure(2), imshow(q)
figure(3)
subplot(121), imshow(a)
subplot(122), imshow(b)
figure(4), imshow(c)
```

Note that there are differences at the edges. In the Mathematica documentation, it vaguely says:

> At the edges of an image, MedianFilter/MinFilter/MaxFilter uses smaller neighborhoods.

But there is no direct match for this behavior, instead MATLAB gives you the option to customize the padding at the boundaries of the images.

[image: screenshot1]

---

#### @belisarius solution

```
%# read image
I = im2double(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KCd1.jpg'));

%# LaplacianGaussianFilter[]
II = imfilter( I , fspecial('log', [2 2]*2+1, (2*2+1)/2) );

%# ImageAdjust[]
for k=1:size(II,3)
    mn = min(min( II(:,:,k) )); mx = max(max( II(:,:,k) ));
    II(:,:,k) = ( II(:,:,k) - mn ) ./ (mx-mn);
end

%# Binarize[]
BW = im2bw(II, 0.6);

%# DeleteSmallComponents[]
BW = bwareaopen(BW, 2, 8);

%# show images
figure
subplot(121), imshow(BW)
subplot(122), imshow( imoverlay(I,BW,[0 1 0]) )
```

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was completely lost in the Mathematica.

Comment: glad I could help. I forgot to mention that I am using the IMOVERLAY function by Steve Eddins: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/03/28/image-overlays/

Answer (score 9):

The following may help a bit (Code in Mathematica):

```
DeleteSmallComponents[
 Binarize[
   LaplacianGaussianFilter[i, 2],
 .6],
 2]
```

[image]

Image composition to show the matching:

```
ImageCompose[i, {i1, .4}] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! I will try to apply your suggestions tomorrow. The point is that I need as little noise as possible as the noise ruins my computations. I need to get the overall orientation of the fibers and the noise deforms the results quite significantly.

Comment: @Oldrich Hmmm ... perhaps you should specify the term "orientation" better

Comment: Well it is about orientation tensors -> more complicated. That is why I did not want to go that deep into it. But lets say that less is better for me. So I prefer to have 70 % of all the fibers and almost no noise than 90 % of all the fibers with a lot of noise.

Comment: @belisarius: I think you forgot to apply `ImageAdjust` after the LoG filter and before `Binarize[]`

Answer (score 5):

Try `MinDetect` and `MaxDetect`.

```
s = Sharpen @ ImageAdjust @ originalimage
{min, max} = {s~MinDetect~.3, s~MaxDetect~.7}
min~MedianFilter~5~MinFilter~5~MaxFilter~25~MinFilter~20
{min~ImageSubtract~%, max~ImageMultiply~%}
ImageAdd @@ %
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks good! I have tried to rewrite it to Matlab (I do not have Mathematica) but I was not successful so far. I will keep trying but if you also knew Matlab I would really appreciate if you could also provide Matlab version.

Comment: @Nakilon: I tried your code in Mathematica, but I'm not getting the same result. What is `s` exactly, is it the original image?

Comment: @Amro, my fault! Lost one line. Fixed.

Comment: +1 thanks now its working. @OldrichSvec: I posted a somewhat equivalent version in MATLAB.

Answer (score 4):

Read about [Edge Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection). Thats what you need in this case. a threshold will not help you.
Fibers (which are mostly straight) will be relatively easy to detect. But as there is a chapter on the Wikipedia site: "Why edge detection is a non-trivial task"...

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate on that? I could spend years studying the topic, but I do not have that much time. Anything which works is just fine for me right now :)

Comment: you can check if this codeProject works for you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Canny_Edge_Detection.aspx . Canny edge detection is ok. But as always, if you know what you are doing you will get better results...